# Regexp to get the content of a string between two quotes, starting with a given name

Tags: java, regex

I have multiple lines in an xml file.

My lines are like `<Blog blogDescription="bla bla bla" description="" date="2010-10-10"/>`

I'm working on all lines starting with `"<Blog"` where I want to :

1. Set the content of blogDescription field into description field
2. Remove blogDescription field

So my line would be like :

```
<Blog description="bla bla bla" date="2010-10-10"/>
```

I don't know what kind of regexp i can use, I only get the line with :

```
"^<(Blog) .*"
```

And I remove blogDescription field with :

```
" blogDescription="
```

But I don't know how to put the `blogDescription` value into description value.

Answer (score 2):

If you're already working with XML that is correctly formatted, rather than building a parser yourself via regex, why not just use one of the XML parsers available to you? There are many available to do this.

See this related question:
[Parsing XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787893/parsing-xml-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String val = "<Blog blogDescription=\"bla bla bla\" description=\"\" date=\"2010-10-10\"/>";
    String regex = "^<Blog (blogDescription=\"[^\"]*\"\\s+).*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(val);
    matcher.matches();

    MatchResult result = matcher.toMatchResult();
    System.out.println(result.group(1));
    String resultString = val.replace(result.group(1), "");
    System.out.println(resultString);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this:

```
String str = "<Blog blogDescription=\"bla bla bla\" description=\"\" date=\"2010-10-10\"/>";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("blogDescription=\"([^\"]+)\"\\s+description=\"[^\"]*\"",
            "description=\"$1\""));
```

.I don't know  if there  is any newline in the string.
it would not work if you have one newline in the string liking:
blogDescription="bla \nbla"\n description=;